# Finding text in Range based on some values

Tags: excel

I have a table that I want to perform calculations on. The table contains 3 fields. I want to get data from the table based on the value of the third column.

ColA  |  ColB  |  ColC

Val1A |  Val1B | Val1C
Val2A |  Val2B | Val2C
Val3A |  Val3B | Val3C
Val4A |  Val4B | Val4C
ValnA |  ValnB | ValnC

Now, I want to see if Val1C equals to say, xyz, and Val1A equals abc, then calculate some formula or equation.

How can I do that? I tried to use VLOOKUP but failed :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for here is the AND formula, which will return TRUE if (and only if) all of its arguments are TRUE.

The syntax is as follows:

```
=AND(argument1,argument2,...)
```

In your example, you could nest AND within an IF statement, so that your chosen 'formula or equation' will only fire if the conditions are true.

For example (formatted to two lines for ease of reading - enter the formula as one line:)

```
=IF ( AND(Val1C=xyx, Val1A=abc) , [action if conditions are met] ,
 [action if conditions are not met] )
```

Roughly speaking this translates as "Check if Val1C = xyz and Val1A = abc; if the answer to that is 'TRUE', then process [action if conditions are met]; if the answer to that is 'FALSE' then process [action if conditions are not met]."

There is an alternative approach you can use, whereby you concatenate the contents of Val1A and Val1C into a single value, and then run your VLOOKUP formula based on the result. Concatenation can be done with the (helpfully named) CONCATENATE formula - or, if you're using Excel 2007 or later, with the & symbol - as follows:

```
-- method 1
=CONCATENATE(Val1C, Val1A)
--method 2
=Val1C & Val1A
```

The concatenation method works nicely if you have text-type values, but can be a bit tricky if you're using numbers, dates or other non-text formats, as Excel tends to do odd things with datatype conversion when you start using those cells in formula references. It may also be a good idea to insert a symbol inbetween the two values in your concatenation - such as Val1C & "-" & Val1A - but this is really a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks psyk0, but this will not work for a range .. Say I need to look for a value in range A1:C5, this will not work .. I need to look for a specific value (may be repetitive), if the value is found say in row 3, I need to get the value of A2 and B2